# Xamarin forms app crashing on startup regardless of Debug/Release

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I have had this weird problem with my Xamarin Forms app. It seems to crash on startup. I have tried changing the Android Linker settings but regardless of the settings it still seems to crash. It used to work on Debug mode but not working anymore. I have tried deleting the bin and obj files. I have tried deleting and updating the NuGet packages. Any help would be appreciated. I have checked in the "Main Activity" method for any missing constructors but there doesn't seem to be any missing.

Here is the stack trace below:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NotSupportedException: Could not activate JNI Handle 0xbfe1bd38 (key_handle 0xfcb6ecf) of Java type 'md5a4d2fdb8e3028a798e3d0ab6628e2c4b/MainActivity' as managed type 'TeaTotal.Droid.MainActivity'. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'TeaTotal.Droid.MainActivity' threw an exception. ---> System.MissingMethodException: Default constructor not found for type Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.CurrentPlatform
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceMono (System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00085] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:171 
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x0001a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:153 
   at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor (System.Boolean publicOnly, System.Boolean skipCheckThis, System.Boolean fillCache, System.Threading.StackCrawlMark& stackMark) [0x0002a] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/rttype.cs:5638 
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type, System.Boolean nonPublic) [0x00040] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:201 
   at System.Activator.CreateInstance (System.Type type) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4468/f913a78a/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/activator.cs:134 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.Platform.get_Instance () [0x00054] in <77043900ca604149b85ba57dba9fe35b>:0 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient.GetApplicationInstallationId () [0x00004] in <77043900ca604149b85ba57dba9fe35b>:0 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor (System.Uri applicationUri, System.String applicationKey, System.Net.Http.HttpMessageHandler[] handlers) [0x00028] in <77043900ca604149b85ba57dba9fe35b>:0 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor (System.Uri applicationUri, System.String applicationKey) [0x00000] in <77043900ca604149b85ba57dba9fe35b>:0 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor (System.Uri applicationUri) [0x00000] in <77043900ca604149b85ba57dba9fe35b>:0 
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceClient..ctor (System.String applicationUrl) [0x00007] in <77043900ca604149b85ba57dba9fe35b>:0 
   at TeaTotal.Droid.MainActivity..cctor () [0x00000] in C:\TT\Droid\MainActivity.cs:31
```

Comment: Could you update your post with the code of your MainActivity file?

Comment: Could you please check the target android API Level to see if it fits your device/emulator. And please also try clean and rebuild the solution.